# Silverlight , animation in the custom control

Tags: custom-controls, silverlight-5.0, resourcedictionary

I have created a custom Control in Silverlight,
I've added the template into the generic.xaml file Resource dictionary.
In Addition to the Template I have put the StoryBoard Object to this Dictionary

```xml
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
xmlns:WidgetBase="clr-namespace:WidgetBase">

<Style TargetType="WidgetBase:WidgetBase">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="WidgetBase:WidgetBase">
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="10">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="FrameContainer">
                        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness=".6"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" CornerRadius="10" Padding="3" MaxWidth="70" MaxHeight="30" Margin="5">
                            <Border.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect Color="Gray"></DropShadowEffect>
                            </Border.Effect>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <StackPanel.Resources>
                                    <Style TargetType="Image">
                                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="16"></Setter>
                                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="16"></Setter>
                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,0,3,0"></Setter>
                                        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"></Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                </StackPanel.Resources>

                                <Image x:Name="MinimizeButton" Source="../Icons/Deep_Fav.png" />
                                <Image x:Name="RestoreButton" Source="../Icons/Deep_Faq.png" />
                                <Image x:Name="CloseButton" Source="../Icons/Deep_Close.png"/>


                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>

                        <Border BorderBrush="Gray" x:Name="DragBorder" BorderThickness=".8"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" CornerRadius="10" Background="Black" Cursor="SizeNWSE">

                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Margin="10"/>
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

**<Storyboard x:Key="CloseAnimation">
    <DoubleAnimation     Storyboard.TargetProperty="UIElement.Opacity"
                         Duration="00:00:02" From="1.0" To="0.0" 
                         AutoReverse="False">
    </DoubleAnimation>
</Storyboard>**
```

How can I Use the Storyboard from Resource Dictionary from Code Behind ?
I am wiring the click event to the button from Template:

```
 (this.GetTemplateChild("CloseButton") as Image).MouseLeftButtonDown += Close;
```

And then In the event handler I'd like to play animation on a user Control.

Pls can anyone help ?

Thanks.